# The unexpected selection and merging behavior of clojure.set/join

Tags: join, clojure, relation

I wanted to overwrite some default value in a relation with some specific values and stumbled upon some behavior I don't quite understand.

```
(clojure.set/join 
#{
  {:a 1 :b nil :c "2"}
  {:a 2 :b "2" :c nil}
  {:a 3 :b 1 :c 5}
} 
#{
  {:a 1 :b 44}
  {:a 3 :b 11 :c 55}
} 
{:a :a})
```

resolves to `#{{:a 3, :c 5, :b 1} {:c "2", :a 1, :b nil}}`.

If I flip the arguments I get the same result.

```
(clojure.set/join 
#{
  {:a 1 :b 44}
  {:a 3 :b 11 :c 55}
} 
#{
  {:a 1 :b nil :c "2"}
  {:a 2 :b "2" :c nil}
  {:a 3 :b 1 :c 5}
} 
{:a :a})
```

also resolves to `#{{:a 3, :c 5, :b 1} {:c "2", :a 1, :b nil}}`.

What I expected (at least from the first statement) was `#{{:a 3, :c 55, :b 11} {:c "2", :a 1, :b 44}}`.

First question: Why don't I get what I expect?

Second question: Why do I get the same result regardless of argument order?

---

Just in case someone wants my solution to my problem stated in the beginning

```
(
  (fn [default, data, key] 
    (->> default 
      (map (fn [defaultEntry] 
        (merge 
          defaultEntry 
          (->> data (filter (fn [dataEntry] (= (key defaultEntry) (key dataEntry)))) first)
        )
      ))
    )
  )
  #{
    {:a 1 :b nil :c "2"}
    {:a 2 :b "2" :c nil}
    {:a 3 :b 1 :c 5}
  } 
  #{
    {:a 1 :b 44}
    {:a 3 :b 11 :c 55}
  } 
  :a
)
```

(Warning: Assumes that `key` is unique!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [clojure.set/join code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/set.clj#L130) we can see that the set with fewer elements is used as an index and the set with more elements is reduced by looking for each element in the index and keeping the merged version for each found item.

```
(defn join
  "When passed 2 rels, returns the rel corresponding to the natural
  join. When passed an additional keymap, joins on the corresponding
  keys."
  ; 2-arity version removed for brevity
  ([xrel yrel km] ;arbitrary key mapping
   (let [[r s k] (if (<= (count xrel) (count yrel))
                   [xrel yrel (map-invert km)]
                   [yrel xrel km])
         idx (index r (vals k))]
     (reduce (fn [ret x]
               (let [found (idx (rename-keys (select-keys x (keys k)) k))]
                 (if found
                   (reduce #(conj %1 (merge %2 x)) ret found)
                   ret)))
             #{} s))))
```

That's why you'll the get same result with `(set/join a b)` or `(set/join b a)`, except if both sets are of the same length, which is not your case.

It also explains why you get `#{{:a 3, :c 5, :b 1} {:c "2", :a 1, :b nil}}` instead of `#{{:a 3, :c 55, :b 11} {:c "2", :a 1, :b 44}}`: The values in the maps from the longer set take precedence over the values from the shorter set when there's a match.

Comment: Any ideas about why that was implemented like that?

Comment: Perhaps it's that set/join implements a strict [natural join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Natural_join_.28.E2.8B.88.29) or in the case of the 3-arity overload an [equijoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#.CE.B8-join_and_equijoin). I understand that in the equijoin (that's your case) it is assumed that no attributes are repeated on both sides, so there are no guarantess on the result when attributes (apart from the join attrs) match (:b and :c in your case).

Comment: In all the examples that I've seen using set/join, the only attributes that are present in the relations from both sets are those used to match. If that's the case, set/join is commutative. I think that's what the implementation assumes