# The meaning of relations in Clojure

Tags: clojure, relation

I see in the [documentation of join](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set/join) the xrel and yrel. What does a relation mean here?

Answer (score 1):

here rel(ation) means `set of maps`,

As I see it, it just states that in the context of `clojure.set/join` it's more meaningful to talk about `relation` instead constantly saying 'set of maps where the map-keys are the field-descriptors'

Comment: thanks. and what is actually this set.join doing? Is it something like doseq for maps?

Comment: it does a natural join as stated in the docs - it produces all combinations of fields (where the fields from relx and rely match) - see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Natural_join)

Comment: My [anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31527090/1389573) to a [specific question on set/join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526709/the-unexpected-selection-and-merging-behavior-of-clojure-set-join) might be of help too.